# How to pass correct client ip from nginx running in one container to python-flask app running 2nd container?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, docker, iptables

I have two docker container running, one is a nginx as reverse-proxy on 80,443 that accepts http and https requests and passes them to the another container which is a Python Flask App container running on port 8000.

If I run nginx on host machine instead of running it in a container, flask app can read the correct client ip address but

if I run nginx also in a container, it shows only docker0 network interface's ip address to the flask application running in 2nd container, no matter what the actual client ip is.

In Python Flask app I use the following code:

```
ip = request.environ.get('HTTP_X_REAL_ip', request.remote_addr)
```

Docker-Compose File:

```
mongo:
  restart: always
  image: mongo:latest
  ports:
    - '27017'
  volumes:
    - /opt/python/apps/myapp/PersistentDockerVolumes/mongo/data:/data/db/

redis:
  restart: always
  build: ./redis
  command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.rb"]
  ports:
    - '6379'

myapp:
  restart: always
  build: ./myapp
  command: ["gunicorn", "--config=gunicorn.py", "myapp:app"]
  environment:
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND: 'noninteractive'
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED: 'true'
  links:
    - mongo
    - redis
  volumes:
    - /opt/python/apps/myapp/logs/myapp/:/myapp/log/
  ports:
    - '8000'

nginx:
  restart: always
  build: ./nginx
  command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
  links:
    - myapp
  volumes:
    - /opt/python/apps/myapp/logs/nginx:/etc/nginx/logs
  volumes_from:
    - myapp
  ports:
    - '80:80'
    - '443:443'
```

In the nginx config, I have defined an proxy pass to myapp:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

I tried looking for solution, but none of them is for python flask application. My scenario is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729849/passing-correct-ip-via-linked-docker-containers-from-nginx-to-jetty), but the difference is I have it for Flask instead of Jetty and the solution is very specific for Jetty.

Another thread which is partially similar is [here](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/issues/130), scenario discussed in this thread is nginx server behind nginx reverse proxy, which is again not the same scenario, and I am skeptical about running docker with iptables disabled.

Comment: I have a reverse proxy nginx container (not using the jwilder one) that uses an upstream config to a python tornado server. Do you have one of those set? It just uses the hostname of the other container

Comment: It *looks* like this is a duplicate - if `request.access_route` doesn't have the *real* IP, just ping me with a comment here and I'll re-open.

Comment: Thanks @Sean for pointing this out. I tried looking for possible duplicates but I couldn't find the exact one you have shared.

I looked for all possible similar questions while writing my question but none of it was discussed in same context compare to what I was facing.

I guess I wouldn't have found it myself as I didn't knew it was a flask problem, after reading the github link that I have mentioned in my question, I was thinking that it is a docker issue.